# Anybody who have used Django and JQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, autocomplete

Is there anybody out there who have used Django and JQuery Autocomplete? Am stuck on this and i will highly appreciate to see how someone else has done this! especially without using the AutocompleteWidget!

Gath

Answer (score 3):

There are some easy to follow examples in this GitHub mirror of [django-autocomplete](http://github.com/henriquebastos/django-autocomplete).

Answer (score 1):

some time ago I put together a small tutorial on this, you might find that useful... it's [here](http://www.michelepasin.org/techblog/?p=359)